# Functions to use Python, matplotlib and pandas in Statistics

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have to do these with Python, Matplotlib, and Pandas.

- read a CSV file separated with ","  and decimals
- count ALL the lines of the file
- plot a bar graph with the values of the column year of the same file
- find the expected value of ALL the values of a column
- find the quartile (with Python and his libraries).
- find the proper sample size.

What I ask you is what are the best methods/functions to do all these things.
The only thing which I have reached to write is this.

```
pd.read_csv('pandas_tutorial_read.csv', delimiter=';')
```

Here is a problem very similar to what I have to do.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sy7vqq2x2740u9d/AACFap-NPA04znDMNX5W9wdza?dl=0

Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate your honesty about what you've tried so far!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Try to write some code, and if you get some error come back here and ask for help.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm locked. I dont' reach. I have to do a work like this and i don't know what to use. I have already watched many tutorials and the documentation but it wasn't enough.

Comment: How did you find yourself in a situation where you cannot possibly do what you have been asked to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read in a csv, you can use this code. Delimiter is not required if input file is comma separated.

```
df = pd.read_csv('path')
```

To count all rows, use shape attribute of df.

```
rows = df.shape[0]
```

To plot a bar graph use this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(col1,col2)
```

If you mean regressing value by "expected value" use Imputer. You can find documentation online.

Quantiling can be done like this.

```
df[col].quantile([0,0.25,0.5,0.75])
```

Didn't understand what you mean by "sample size".

There are tonnes of documentation and tutorials out there. All the best!

Comment: Thank you. For sample size i mean how many numbers  i have to considerate.